# simple_form custom input and two fields with same id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I'm trying to create custom input for datepicker using SimpleForm gem

```
class DatepickerInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input
    out = ''
    out << @builder.text_field(attribute_name, input_html_options)
    out << @builder.hidden_field(attribute_name, { :class => attribute_name.to_s + "-alt"}) 
  end
end
```

but when data is generated both inputs have same ids

```
<input class="datepicker" id="performance_cycle_start_date" name="performance_cycle[start_date]" type="text">
<input class="start_date_internal" id="performance_cycle_start_date" name="performance_cycle[start_date]" type="hidden">
```

how can I change id to something like "#{original_id}_internal_format"

P.S. code for this input taken from http://www.chadcf.com/blog/jqueryui-datepicker-rails-and-simpleform-easy-way

Answer (score 0):

As the blog says we can give Id, try as below. This will ensure both fields to have different 'id' attribute.

```
class DatepickerInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input
    out = ''
    out << @builder.text_field(attribute_name, input_html_options)
    out << @builder.hidden_field(attribute_name, { :class => attribute_name.to_s + "-alt", :id => "#{attribute_name.to_s}_internal_format" }) 
  end
end
```

Comment: attribute_name.to_s return only field name e.g. start_date, but original id has also model name - performance_review_start_date